# NoMethodError in Index: How to Define the Nested Attributes?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, undefined, nested-attributes, cocoon-gem

NoMethodError in Quantifieds#index

undefined method `date_value' for #Quantified:0x007ff3fe7d6c08

How do I define date_value & result_value so it works in the quantifieds index?

```html
<!-- Default bootstrap panel contents -->

<div id="values" class="panel panel-default">
  
  <div class="panel-heading"><h4><b>AVERAGE</b></h4></div>

  <!-- Table -->
<table>
  <% @averaged_quantifieds.each do |averaged| %>
    <% if averaged.user == current_user %>
        <th class="value">
          <%= link_to edit_quantified_path(averaged) do %>
          <%= averaged.name %>
          <% end %>
          (<%= averaged.metric %>)
        </th>
      <tbody class="value"> 
          <td><%= averaged.date_value.strftime("%m-%Y") %></td>
          <td><%= averaged.result_value %></td>
      </tbody>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
</table>
</div>

<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>

<!-- Default bootstrap panel contents -->
<div id="values" class="panel panel-default">
  
  <div class="panel-heading"><h4><b>INSTANCE</b></h4></div>

  <!-- Table -->
<table>
  <% @instance_quantifieds.each do |instance| %>
    <% if instance.user == current_user %>
        <th class="value">
          <%= link_to edit_quantified_path(instance) do %>
          <%= instance.name %>
          <% end %>
          (<%= instance.metric %>)
        </th>
      <tbody class="value"> 
          <td><%= instance.date_value.strftime("%m-%Y") %></td>
          <td><%= instance.result_value %></td>
      </tbody>
    <% end %>
    <% end %>
</table>
</div>

  <div class="values-button">
  <%= link_to new_quantified_path, class: 'btn'  do %>
  <b><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"</span></b>
  <% end %>
  </div>
```

date_value & result_value are derived from f.simple_fields_for :results in the _form. I am using cocoon to create my nested attributes.

```html
= simple_form_for @quantified do |f|
  .america
    %form
      = f.select :categories, Quantified::CATEGORIES
      %br/
      %br/
      .form-group
        = f.text_field :name,  class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter Name'
      .form-group
        = f.text_field :metric,  class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter Metric'
      #results
        = f.simple_fields_for :results do |result|
          = render 'result_fields', :f => result
        = link_to_add_association 'Add Result', f, :results
      %br/
      = button_tag(type: 'f.submit', class: "btn") do
        %span.glyphicon.glyphicon-plus
```

```html
.nested-fields
 .form-group
  = f.text_field :result_value, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Enter Result'
  %br
  = f.date_select :date_value, :order => [:month, :year], class: 'date-select'
  = link_to_remove_association "Remove Result", f
```

I think the solution maybe found in altering the controller:

```html
class QuantifiedsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_quantified, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
   @quantified = Result.all.order("date_value")
   @averaged_quantifieds = current_user.quantifieds.averaged
   @instance_quantifieds = current_user.quantifieds.instance
  end

  def show
  end

  def new
    @quantified = current_user.quantifieds.build
    @quantified.results.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @quantified = current_user.quantifieds.build(quantified_params)
    if @quantified.save
      redirect_to quantifieds_url, notice: 'Quantified was successfully created'
    else
      render action: 'new'
  end
end

  def update
    if @quantified.update(quantified_params)
      redirect_to quantifieds_url, notice: 'Goal was successfully updated'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
  end
end

  def destroy
    @quantified.destroy
    redirect_to quantifieds_url
  end

  private
    def set_quantified
      @quantified = Quantified.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @quantified = current_user.quantifieds.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to quantifieds_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this goal" if @quantified.nil?
    end

    def quantified_params
      params.require(:quantified).permit(:categories, :name, :metric, :result, :date, results_attributes: [:id, :result_value, :date_value, :_destroy])
    end
end
```

Here's some more code to give more context:

**routes.rb**

```html
Rails.application.routes.draw do

  resources :goals

  resources :values

  resources :quantifieds do
    resources :results
  end
  devise_for :users
  root 'values#index'
  get "about" => "pages#about"
```

**schema.rb**

```html
# encoding: UTF-8
# This file is auto-generated from the current state of the database. Instead
# of editing this file, please use the migrations feature of Active Record to
# incrementally modify your database, and then regenerate this schema definition.
#
# Note that this schema.rb definition is the authoritative source for your
# database schema. If you need to create the application database on another
# system, you should be using db:schema:load, not running all the migrations
# from scratch. The latter is a flawed and unsustainable approach (the more migrations
# you'll amass, the slower it'll run and the greater likelihood for issues).
#
# It's strongly recommended that you check this file into your version control system.

ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150123210404) do

  create_table "goals", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.date     "deadline"
    t.boolean  "accomplished", default: false
    t.datetime "created_at",                   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",                   null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  add_index "goals", ["deadline"], name: "index_goals_on_deadline"
  add_index "goals", ["user_id"], name: "index_goals_on_user_id"

  create_table "quantifieds", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "categories"
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "metric"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  add_index "quantifieds", ["categories"], name: "index_quantifieds_on_categories"
  add_index "quantifieds", ["user_id"], name: "index_quantifieds_on_user_id"

  create_table "results", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "result_value"
    t.date     "date_value"
    t.integer  "quantified_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",    null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",    null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  add_index "results", ["quantified_id"], name: "index_results_on_quantified_id"
  add_index "results", ["user_id"], name: "index_results_on_user_id"

  create_table "users", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     default: "", null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token"
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          default: 0,  null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip"
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.string   "name"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", unique: true
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true

  create_table "values", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "categories"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.integer  "user_id"
  end

  add_index "values", ["categories"], name: "index_values_on_categories"
  add_index "values", ["user_id"], name: "index_values_on_user_id"

end
```

**_create_results.rb**

```html
class CreateResults < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :results do |t|
      t.string :result_value
      t.date :date_value
      t.belongs_to :quantified, index: true

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_foreign_key :results, :quantifieds
  end
end
```

**_add_user_id_to_results.rb**

```html
class AddUserIdToResults < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :results, :user_id, :integer
    add_index :results, :user_id
  end
end
```

**quantified.rb**

```html
class Quantified < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
  scope :averaged,  -> { where(categories: 'averaged') }
  scope :instance,  -> { where(categories: 'instance') }
  has_many :results
 accepts_nested_attributes_for :results, :reject_if => :all_blank, :allow_destroy => true

 CATEGORIES = ['averaged', 'instance']

end
```

**result.rb**

```html
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
 belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :quantified
end
```

**Full trace**

```html
activemodel (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:433:in `method_missing'
app/views/quantifieds/index.html.erb:18:in `block in _app_views_quantifieds_index_html_erb__3407997734302574408_70263238235460'
activerecord (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
activerecord (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_record/relation/delegation.rb:46:in `each'
app/views/quantifieds/index.html.erb:9:in `_app_views_quantifieds_index_html_erb__3407997734302574408_70263238235460'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/template.rb:145:in `block in render'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:166:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/template.rb:333:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/template.rb:143:in `render'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:54:in `block (2 levels) in render_template'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/abstract_renderer.rb:39:in `instrument'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:53:in `block in render_template'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:61:in `render_with_layout'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:52:in `render_template'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/template_renderer.rb:14:in `render'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:42:in `render_template'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/renderer/renderer.rb:23:in `render'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:100:in `_render_template'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/streaming.rb:217:in `_render_template'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:83:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:32:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/renderers.rb:37:in `render_to_body'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/abstract_controller/rendering.rb:25:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:16:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block (2 levels) in render'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `block in ms'
/Users/galli01anthony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/benchmark.rb:294:in `realtime'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/core_ext/benchmark.rb:12:in `ms'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:41:in `block in render'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:84:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
activerecord (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:25:in `cleanup_view_runtime'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:40:in `render'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:10:in `default_render'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:5:in `send_action'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:198:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:20:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:117:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:151:in `block in halting_and_conditional'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:234:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:169:in `block in halting'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:92:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_process_action_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/abstract_controller/callbacks.rb:19:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/rescue.rb:29:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:31:in `block in process_action'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:20:in `instrument'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:164:in `instrument'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/instrumentation.rb:30:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/params_wrapper.rb:250:in `process_action'
activerecord (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_record/railties/controller_runtime.rb:18:in `process_action'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:137:in `process'
actionview (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_view/rendering.rb:30:in `process'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:195:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal/rack_delegation.rb:13:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_controller/metal.rb:236:in `block in action'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:73:in `dispatch'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:42:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:43:in `block in serve'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `each'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/journey/router.rb:30:in `serve'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:802:in `call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:35:in `block in call'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `catch'
warden (1.2.3) lib/warden/manager.rb:34:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/etag.rb:24:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/conditionalget.rb:25:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/head.rb:13:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/params_parser.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/flash.rb:260:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:225:in `context'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:220:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:560:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:36:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:647:in `call'
activerecord (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_record/migration.rb:378:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:29:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:88:in `_run_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:734:in `_run_call_callbacks'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:73:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:78:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:30:in `call'
railties (4.2.0.rc3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:38:in `call_app'
railties (4.2.0.rc3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `block in call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:26:in `tagged'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:68:in `tagged'
railties (4.2.0.rc3) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:20:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:21:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:22:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/runtime.rb:18:in `call'
activesupport (4.2.0.rc3) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:28:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (4.2.0.rc3) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:113:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:113:in `call'
railties (4.2.0.rc3) lib/rails/engine.rb:518:in `call'
railties (4.2.0.rc3) lib/rails/application.rb:164:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/lock.rb:17:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/content_length.rb:15:in `call'
rack (1.6.0) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:89:in `service'
/Users/galli01anthony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:138:in `service'
/Users/galli01anthony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/httpserver.rb:94:in `run'
/Users/galli01anthony/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.3/lib/ruby/2.1.0/webrick/server.rb:295:in `block in start_thread'
```

Please let me know if you need any more code or comments to bring this question to a resolution. God speed.

Comment: Dude, too much code! The short answer seems to be that you don't have a date_value and a result_value column in the database for the quantifieds table, so where do these values come from? Did you mean to use created_at and metric?

Comment: Sorry I'll add less code in the future. I'm trying to pull those values in from the "results" table into the "quantified" table because the results are a nested attribute of quantified. As you can see I created the appropriate relationships in the rb files, but my guess is that I'm leaving something out in the Quantifieds controller. I could be mistaken. @Satya

Comment: I tried adding those values you listed to the quantified table, but now I get this error: undefined method `strftime'. I reverted back the code so the problem still lies: undefined method `date_value'. @Satya

Comment: I think you have to do something with `simple_fields_for` in your view, which I have never used, so you're on your own there, sorry. As for `strftime`, that only works on `Time` or `DateTime` objects. Once your nested models are correctly set up, you can use `strftime`just fine.

Comment: Speaking of models, can you show the `quantified` and `result` models?

Comment: @Satya I added the code as requested =]

Comment: Do you have the stacktrace (the lines following the error message) for the NoMethodError? As Kelseydh points out below, the stacktrace is more interesting than the actual error message.

Comment: Thks @Satya! I added the full trace to the bottom.  And now I know why it's called stackoverflow ;)

Comment: Alright, so that's coming from the view, I think from the `averaged.date_value` and `averaged.result_value`. Because `averaged` is an instance of Quantified, and `date_value` and `result_value` are attributes of `Result` instances. Now you have a Quantified has_many Result(s) going on, so how does a Quantified get a single date_value and result_value? Might help to state it in domain terms, i.e. what you're trying to achieve. I don't think the forms (and nested attributes) are in play at all for this particular error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Answer to Your Specific Problem:

In your index action you have:

```
@quantified = Result.all.order("date_value")
```

Calling *`.all`* **before** *`.order`* is the cause of your error.

In Rails ActiveRecord, the `.all` command *immediately* triggers a fetch of items from the database.

Since database IO fetching commands like `.where` and `.order` exist to shape how (or what) data is fetched from the database, you need to call them in your code *before a database retrieval gets triggered* by a command like `.all`:

```
@quantified = Result.order("date_value").all
```

For better clarity it may be ideal to specify ascending or descending ordering in this query, e.g. `Result.order("date_value ASC").all`, or if the data always gets used in this order, to make your ordering a `default_scope` within the `Result` model.

---

## General Advice When Debugging `Undefined Method` "method_name" errors:

In your question I noticed you didn't include the *class* information of the object affected by your error, making it hard to diagnose correctly the source of your problem (whether you had the correct object).

**TIP: When diagnosing an error, check that an object exists FIRST before looking into the method flagged by the error.**

Why?  Because many `undefined method "method_name"` errors are not *actually* caused by `method_name` being `undefined`, but rather because the **object itself** is `nil` or an incorrect class.

**`NoMethodError: undefined method 'method_name'` can be a red herring** that misleads you when you have an object that isn't loaded or instantiated.

To properly diagnose a NoMethodError, it's essential to check *first* that an object's `class` is defined correctly before you start trying to debug it.  Without doing this, it's very easy to go down a rabbit hole looking into problems that might exist with *method_name*, when really the problem lies with your object not existing.

To check an object's class within an `undefined method` error just look for the `for xxx:Class` part of the error.  This describes the object & its class.  If your object is nil or doesn't exist, the undefined method error will display **`for nil:NilClass`**.

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `date_time' for nil:NilClass
```

Unfortunately its easy here to get focused on the `date_time` part of this error message, and not that the `NoMethodError` message is referencing a *nil* class.  In a NoMethodError like above where our object is *nil*, `'date_time'` simply represents a point in code where we unsucessfully called a method against a `nil` object.  To solve a NoMethodError on a nil:NilClass object correctly, what matters is looking into *why* the object itself is not instantiating.